# How to have a function return both index and value of an array?

Tags: c#, return, tuples, ref, out

This function counts how often letter occur in a given string and puts that in an array (index is ascii-number of letter and value ist counted occurrences). Now I need to return both the letter (which it already does) and the value. Just by reading online I couldn't figure out how to use ref and alternatives to do that.

```
static char MostCommonLetter(string s)
    {
        int[] occurrances = new int[255];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(s[i]))
            {
                int ascii = (int)s[i];
                occurrances[ascii]++;
            }
        }
        char maxValue = (char)Array.IndexOf(occurrances, occurrances.Max());
        return maxValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# 7 and above, [Value Tuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) are your best bet. You could define your function as follows:

```
static (char letter, int occurrences) MostCommonLetter(string s)
{
    int[] occurrences = new int[255];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(s[i]))
        {
            int ascii = (int)s[i];
            occurrances[ascii]++;
        }
    }
    char letter = (char)Array.IndexOf(occurrences, occurrences.Max());
    return (index: letter, occurrences: occurrences);
}
```

You could then reference the output like so:

```
var (index, occurrences) = MostCommonLetter(yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "out" parameter to return additional parameters from the function.

```
    static char MostCommonLetter(string s, out int maxOccurrance)
    {
        int[] occurrances = new int[255];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(s[i]))
            {
                int ascii = (int)s[i];
                occurrances[ascii]++;
            }
        }

        maxOccurrance = occurrances.Max();
        char maxValue = (char)Array.IndexOf(occurrances, maxOccurrance);

        return maxValue;
    }

    //...

    // In C# 7 and above you can call it like that
    var c = MostCommonLetter("abccd", out int maxOccurrance);

    //// In older version of C# you should just declare out variable before use it
    //int maxOccurrance;
    //var c = MostCommonLetter("abccd", out maxOccurrance);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be using LINQ :

```
string str = "Hello World!";

var result = str.GroupBy(c => c)
                .Select(group => new { Letter = group.Key, Count = group.Count() })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                .First();

char letter = result.Letter;
int count = result.Count;
```

**letter = 'l'**

**count = 3**

Comment: Ah yes, didn't read it… but now I can't delete the downvote, unless you edit the answer, says StackOverflow.

Comment: Down Vote removed.  I beg sorry.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best and flexible way to do what you need in C# is by using a **struct**.

Define a struct in this way and use it to return multiple results at same time (a struct can even contain function… you can see those structs as lightier classes):

```
namespace YourApp.AnyNamespace {

    // Other things

    public struct SampleName
    {
        public char mostCommon;
        public int occurancies;
    }
}
```

Comment: This for sure isn't "The best and flexible way"

Comment: @SlavenTojić anyway, another user reminded about tuples, added in C# 7, that are even easier to use.